# SqlFileStream exception "An invalid parameter was passed to the function"

Tags: c#, exception, sqlfilestream

I'm getting this exception:

> An invalid parameter was passed to the function

when trying to create new instance from `SqlFileStream`.
code:

```
var fileStream = new SqlFileStream(strSqlPath, bytArrContext, FileAccess.Write)
```

I checked for all the parameters non of them are null.
I've been using this same exact code for awhile with no problems, i have no idea what's happening right now.

Comment: What is `strSqlPath` and `bytArrContext` exactly?

Comment: @SonerGönül strSqlPath is the logical path for the file, and bytArrcontext is the transaction context byte array.

Comment: @RASHOMON I think you missed some configuration on server, please check this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128657/How-Do-I-Use-SQL-File-Stream

Comment: @RezaRahmati i already checked this article, didn't help :( but thanks for your reply

Comment: @RASHOMON as another note, did you checked that the folder part of strSqlPath exists on ***Server***?

Comment: @RezaRahmati yes, all the values that were passed to the SqlFileStream were right, i think it's the issue is related to sql transaction or something, not sure, but am working on it.

Comment: What operation? SELECT, INSERT, or UPDATE?

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of transaction. Please do this inside of a transaction scope.

Answer (score 0):

The current answer was not specific enough for me.
The essence is that:

`new SqlFileStream(dataRow["FileStreamPath"].ToString(), (byte[])dataRow["TransactionContext"], FileAccess.Read)`

Should be called within the `TransactionScope`.

When you want to use the SqlFileStream you still have to be within the transaction. You can convert it to for example a regular MemoryStream to use it outside the transaction.